# How can I count 1:N:1 and N:1:N manners?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'd like to do a count in the manner of 1:N:1 and N:1:N.

Here is my query, but it is not doing exactly what I want:

```
Match 
  (V1)-[e1]->(v2)->[e2]->(v3)
With
  Count(distinct(v1.property)) as cntleft , count(distinct(v3.property)) as cntright
Where
 cntleft=1 and cntright=1
Return 
  Count(v2)
```

Comment: Hi, it would be nice to make yourself understandable in words instead of symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working query in Memgraph:

```
MATCH (v1)-[e1]->(v2)-[e2]->(v3)
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT v1) AS left, COUNT(DISTINCT v3) as right, v1, v2, v3
WHERE left = 1 AND right = 1
WITH collect(v2) AS n, v1, v3
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

First, we have to be careful with relationships (->). This kind of construct is not supported:

```
(v2)->[e2]->(v3)
```

because it is enough to put `(v2)-[e2]->(v3)`.

Then, as you can see in the above query, the usage of `DISTINCT` is without the parenthesis, and you don't have to use a certain property to count what you wanted. It is enough to count the distinct nodes.

The other this you have to do is not to forget to pipe `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`, since we need them later on.
I think this part with left and right = 1 is fine, and in the end, I collected these kind of `v2`'s to count all `1:N:1`, instead of `1:v2:1`, `1:v2:1`,..as a result. To see the relationships you got, you can run:

```
MATCH (v1)-[e1]->(v2)-[e2]->(v3)
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT v1) AS left, COUNT(DISTINCT v3) as right, v1, v2, v3
WHERE left = 1 AND right = 1
RETURN v1, collect(v2) AS n, v3;
```

Similarly, for `N:1:N`, I would run:

```
MATCH (v1)-[e1]->(v2)-[e2]->(v3)
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT v2) AS middle, v1, v2, v3
WHERE middle = 1
WITH collect(v1) AS n1, v2, collect(v3) AS n2
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

That is, to discover the nodes:

```
MATCH (v1)-[e1]->(v2)-[e2]->(v3)
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT v2) AS middle, v1, v2, v3
WHERE middle = 1
RETURN collect(v1), v2, collect(v3);
```